# What are packages called in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, rpm

In many distributions, when speaking of a package, the word `RPM` is used. Wikipedia [does not list Debian and Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) as one of them, as their package system is different.

The abbreviation as a word do speak of a package in general is practical though. **Is there a short name that Ubuntu-people use when talking about packages instead of *RPM***?

Comment: Also RPM = Red Hat Package Manager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`deb`

We are a debian based system so our files end in `.deb` and lots of people call those "deb installer file" or "debian installer file".

And the page you refer to is Redhat; [Debian/Ubuntu has its own page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian-Installer) and even a page referring to the [deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) file format.

[And the "package format" page lists them all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_format):

Examples

```
.apk – used by Android
.appx, .appxbundle — used by Microsoft for packaging Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows Phone 8.1 applications.
.deb — Used by Debian and its derivatives, such as Ubuntu, Xubuntu.
ebuild — Used by Gentoo Linux.
PISI — Used by Pardus and derivatives such as Pardus-Anka and Pisi Linux.
.pkg - Used by iPhone, PlayStation 3, Solaris 
PUP and PET — used by Puppy Linux 
QPKG — Used by QNAP NAS devices.
.rpm — Used by Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora, derivatives such as CentOS and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server.
SLP — Used by Stampede Linux.
.tar.xz, .txz — Used by Arch Linux's Pacman package manager.
.tgz, .txz, .tbz, .tlz — Used by Slackware.
```

And to make this future proof: We are switching from a debian installer to [Snappy](https://plus.google.com/+WillCooke/posts/AxfoU3N1Ezo):

> Our plan for 15.10 (which is still being finalised, and will be discussed in more depth at UOS in a couple of weeks) is to have a build based on Snappy Personal and so the current .deb based Desktop Next image will be going away and will be replaced with the new Snappy version.

Comment: Thanks. I was more looking for the catchy word you would use in a a sentence though. Like "You can get this as a ready-made RPM" or "We will have to package this into an RPM to ship it to our production server."

Comment: Or Debian Packages

Comment: Weird though ... "rpm — Used by Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora, derivatives such as CentOS and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server." Suse is a derivative of Redhat? I doubt that :X

Comment: Strongly related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12366/whats-the-best-name-for-debian-packages

Comment: Holy f**! An announcement of that magnitude is made on G+? XO.